Categorical vs binary cross entropy in logistic regression
Suppose I want to adjust this example to the case where instead having a binary Pass/Fail outcome of the exam, we have three grades A, B, C (one can think of C as Fail, B as Pass but not great a grade and A as Pass with a very good grade). Since this is an instance of "multi-class classification: more than two exclusive classes" (see discussion here, it is advised to use what's called "categorical cross-entropy" as opposed to just binary cross-entropy (which is really a special case of the categorical one when there are only two classes). It seems to me that a categorical approach to this would be to define a loss function
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m y_{ij}\log(p_{ij})
$$
where $i$ indexes observations (so $x_i$, time spent studying in the linked example) and

$y_{i1} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got A and zero otherwise,
$y_{12} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got B and zero otherwise,
$y_{13} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got C and zero otherwise,
$p_{ij}$ is our model, determined by the parameters $\theta$ and we naturally have a constraint that $\sum_{j=1}^3 p_{ij} = 1$

But if I insist on trying to have a binary setup that is "compatible" with the categorical setup, I can also define

$\tilde y_{i11} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got A and zero otherwise
$\tilde y_{i12} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got B or C and zero otherwise
$\tilde y_{i21} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got B and zero otherwise
$\tilde y_{i22} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got A or C and zero otherwise
$\tilde y_{i31} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got C and zero otherwise
$\tilde y_{i32} = 1$ if in the corresponding sample the student got A or B and zero otherwise
$\tilde p_{ij1} = p_{ij}$ and $\tilde p_{ij2} = 1 - p_{ij} =  \sum_{l\neq j} p_{il}$ (this I think ensures the "compatibility"?)

We can then define
$$
\mathcal{L}^{(2)}(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^2 \tilde y_{ijk}\log(\tilde p_{ijk})
$$
I am curious to know whether there is any difference between $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{(2)}$. On a purely intuitive level, because of the "compatibility", it seems to me that no new information is supplied to $\mathcal{L}^{(2)}$: the information provided by the terms $\tilde y_{\cdot,\cdot,2}$ all seem essentially redundant. Shouldn't the two loss function be hence equivalent, at least on some level? I was not able to show it with simple manipulations though. If they are different, is it natural to work with $\mathcal{L}$ instead of $\mathcal{L}^{(2)}$? It seems that the "compatibility" ensures we still deal with a multi-classification problem and not just a multi-label problem? Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!
[EDIT: there was a typo in the definition of $\tilde p_{ij2}$]
